# How to mount GCP Bucket in Google Colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, gcsfuse

I want to access the files in my GCP bucket from Colab. I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715268/how-to-import-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-google-colab)

As you can see from the screen shots, there is nothing in the folder after mounting. What am I missing? The Data folder in my bucket is full of data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try prefixing `gs://` to your bucket name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out you can't mount the bucket name + a path within the bucket. Removing the `/Data/` after the name of the bucket led to a successful mount. So since my bucket name is `hellonearth`, the command is just:

```
!gcsfuse --implicit-dirs hellonearth myfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the commands in a wrong way

after `!apt -qq install gcsfuse`

run:

```
!mkdir folderOnColab
!gcsfuse gs://folderOnBucket folderOnColab
```

Then runt `!ls` instead of just `ls`